# A fruity troop of friends

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle

A group of friends love many different fruits and vegetables:

> Gordon loves Mango
>   Monica loves Lemon
>   Ryley loves Cherry
>   Lisa loves Broccoli
>   Otto loves Carrot
>   Percy loves Pepper
>   Toby loves Tomato

What **troop** do these friends form?

Hint:

> They don't share their fruits, but they share something else

Comment: Carrots and Broccoli are technically vegetables, but I enjoyed the puzzle nonetheless, +1

Comment: I'm just gonna say it right now, a carrot is not a fruit.

Comment: @CaelanO'Toole yeah just noticed that, changed it to fruit and vegetables instead

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Each person loves a fruit/vegetable that:

> Ends with the first few letters of their own name
>
>  **Go**rdon loves a Man**go**
>  **Mon**ica loves a Le**mon**
>  **Ry**ley loves a Cher**ry**
>  **Li**sa loves a Brocco**li**
>  **Ot**to loves a Carr**ot**
>  **Per**cy loves a Pep**per**
>  **To**by loves a Toma**to**

Then you can take:

> The letters the friends and the fruits share:
>  G O M O N R Y L I O T P E R T O

And:

> Rearrange them to form the notorious
>  **'Terminology Troop'**

Comment: This is correct! Well done